# How can I access Kinect audio data with OpenNI?

Tags: audio, kinect, openni

I am trying to get audio using Kinect's microphones, but can't even even get the sample running.

The sample that comes with OpenNI (Sample-NiAudioSample) exits with this message:

> No audio node was found!

Has anyone managed to get read audio from a Kinect?
If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Last I checked (a few weeks ago) audio was accessible through the `libfreenect` drivers (OpenKinect) not OpenNI.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I still need to use skeleton data, so I might need to mix OpenNI and freenect. I imagine there will be issues when both libraries attempt to access the device. Would u happen to know if people got both running ? I've spotted something handy(`ModuleLockAwareInterface`) in the OpenNI docs, as I mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446605/how-can-i-access-the-kinect-device-via-openni), but haven't worked out how to use that yet. Any clues ?