# Retrieve the peak of an audio stream from OpenNI

Tags: c++, kinect, openni

I'm attempting to grab the peak level (decibal level or whatnot) from an audio stream from a Kinect using OpenNI.

I've found these:

http://openni.org/docs2/Reference/classxn_1_1_audio_meta_data.html

http://openni.org/docs2/tutorial/smpl_audio.html

But I'm having a hard time piecing it together. I just need an integer of some sort to figure out how loud the surrounding area for the kinect is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using the Audio API provided by OpenNI with no luck, not even the provided sample. I had the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465209/how-can-i-access-kinect-audio-data-with-openni) a while back.

If you're on osx/linux you can use both openni/libfreenect side by side(as admin only on linux) and libfreenect has some experimental audio support.

In the mean time I've found two other projects that look interesting:

1. [HARK](http://winnie.kuis.kyoto-u.ac.jp/HARK/wiki.cgi?page=HARK-KINECT)
2. [MS Kinect-OpenNI Bridge](http://code.google.com/p/kinect-mssdk-openni-bridge/)

I haven't used both, although the second looks promising, so it should be possible to access audio via MS SDK and process data using OpenNI as well.