# Java use libfreenect and OpenNi simultaneous

Tags: java, openni, openkinect

In my project i use the Xbox kinect to recognize handgestures. This is working fine.
So now i need some kind of feedback from the system and i decided to use the LED on
th front of the kinect. The OpenNi driver doesnt support currently the LED control.
In order of this i find out that the OpenKinect libfreenect driver is a popular alternative.

Have anybody of you an idea how i can use Openni and libfreenect simultaneous on the same machine?

I am working on a ubuntu 64bit system.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446605/how-can-i-access-the-kinect-device-via-openni) a few years ago and I used [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/download/) with the osxOpenNI addon. The advantage is that this addon uses both OpenNI and libfreenect.
Libfreenect however is simply used for accessing the hardware OpenNI can't: accelerometer, tilt/motor and the [LED](https://github.com/roymacdonald/ofxOpenNI/blob/master/src/ofxHardwareDriver.h#L63)

I suggest giving that a go and bare in mind you should run the app as `sudo` if you're controlling hardware(LED,etc.). This addon is old now and doesn't support OpenNI2 so I suggest installing OpenNI 1.5

This might a bit more effort than what it's worth. Perhaps if video output isn't enough, some sort of sound feedback would help ?